# Running a piece of code just once in draw() method

Tags: while-loop, processing

I have this code:

```
boolean run;

void setup() {
  size(1440, 900, P3D);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {

  if (keyPressed && key == 'K') {
    run = true;
  } 

  while (run) {
    stroke(100, 200);
    fill(255, 200);
    float xstart = random(10);
    float ynoise = random(10);

    translate(width/2, height/2, 0);

    for (float y=-(height/8);y<=(height/8);y+=3) {
      ynoise += 0.02;
      float xnoise = xstart;

      for (float x=-(height/8);x<=(height/8);x+=3) {
        xnoise += 0.02;
        drawPoint(x, y, noise(xnoise, ynoise));
      }
    }
    run = false;
  }

  if (keyPressed && key == ENTER) {
    background(0);
  }
}

void drawPoint(float x, float y, float noiseFactor) {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x*noiseFactor*4, y*noiseFactor*4, -y);
  float edgeSize = noiseFactor*26;
  ellipse(0, 0, edgeSize, edgeSize);
  popMatrix();
}
```

However, the code in the while loop does not run if I press 'k'. Any suggestions as to why that is?

Comment: Not knowing where `keyPressed` and `key` come from makes it difficult to provide a meaningful response but the obvious answer is: one or both of these variables don't have what you think they should.

Comment: keyPressed and key are part of the Processing API. If I put the code in the while-loop under the if(keyPressed && key == 'K') it will actually run.

Comment: Again (more directly): if you don't provide _all_ of the relevant code, the responses you receive cannot be as useful. If you can't or won't provide the relevant code, you won't get a useful answer.

Comment: I tagged this with the Processing tag, so I assumed people would be familiar with the API and frameworkd of Processing, like others who post in Java don't explain what System does. This is actually all the code needed to run the program in Processing.

Comment: I understand now; having never heard of the Processing language, I was at a disadvantage. I apologize for the noise I've commented on your question!

Comment: Are you pressing caps 'K' ? You test only for it... you can try `(key == 'K' || key == 'k')` to test for both... Also usually it's better to use `void keyPressed()` instead of the field keyPressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing shift + k.... or change your code to:

```
(keyPressed && (key == 'K' || key == 'k'))
```

on a side note... If you want to press once the button and trigger the effect once you will probably be better off with [void keyPressed()](http://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `noLoop()` function and `redraw()` whole scene when key is pressed.

```
void setup() {
  size(1440, 900, P3D);
  background(0);
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  stroke(100, 200);
  fill(255, 200);
  float xstart = random(10);
  float ynoise = random(10);

  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);

  for (float y=-(height/8);y<=(height/8);y+=3) {
    ynoise += 0.02;
    float xnoise = xstart;

    for (float x=-(height/8);x<=(height/8);x+=3) {
      xnoise += 0.02;
      drawPoint(x, y, noise(xnoise, ynoise));
    }
  }
}

void drawPoint(float x, float y, float noiseFactor) {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x*noiseFactor*4, y*noiseFactor*4, -y);
  float edgeSize = noiseFactor*26;
  ellipse(0, 0, edgeSize, edgeSize);
  popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'K' || key == 'k')
    redraw();

  if(key == ENTER){
    redraw();
    background(0);
  }      
}
```